# I was working with Express and node. Using Fetch to POST some data to server. I'm getting 405 err. I havent got any idea on how to solve this

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I was working with Express and node. Using Fetch to POST some data to server. I'm getting 405 err. I havent got any idea on how to solve this.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch node app from "app.listen" by editing:

```js
fetch('api', options)
```

to

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', options)
```

on index2.html on line 27

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see on your screenshot, your node application is running on the port **3000**, but the error on the console says your are getting a 405 error on the localhost but port **5501**.

Is possible that you are trying to reach the wrong url?

Comment: I thought this is how it works. Let me check how to change it. I tried for 3000, but its automatically listening to 5000. Thank you!

Comment: You were correct. I had to share the complete URL